# Javascript how to run async in another thread?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to make an asynchronous method, run the function in a separate thread.

But tests show that async still runs in the same thread as the tab in the browser.

Here is a simple test:

```
async function asyncLoader() {
    while(true) { }
}

var res = await asyncLoader();
```

After running the code, the tab in the browser dies, although it had to run in a separate thread, as is done in C #

How do threads work in javascript? Is it possible to run a separate thread besides Worker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do threads work in javascript?

JavaScript has no native notion of threads.

> Is it possible to run a separate thread besides Worker?

Browsers provide Web Workers. Node.js provides Worker Threads. I'm not aware of any other options.